# Jenkins Finished: FAILURE after Katalon test

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, katalon-studio

I am trying using Jenkins to run Katalon test but I have failure when finish katalon test.

here detail what i have done:

- Run Test on Katalon it's work fine no error,
- jenkins Failed After runing Katalon test,
- Change Jenkinsfile Script with chrome no-sanbox (error)

if you have idea what going on here or find what I miss please let me know, I have work on this few days but still no clue.

**here details of my Jenkinsfile, I have declare all variable before.**

```
stage ("Regression Test") {
        echo 'regression test'
        node ('kre-centos') {
            cleanWs deleteDirs: true
            checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'ci-cd', url: "${katalonRepoUrl}"]], branches: [[name: "${katalonBranch}"]]]
            
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'katalon-api-key', variable: 'secret')]) {
                echo "workspace : ${workspace}"
                sh """
                pwd
                ls
                /katalon01/katalon-studio-engine/katalonc -noSplash -runMode=console \
                -projectPath='${workspace}/${katalonProjectName}' -retry=0 \
                -testSuiteCollectionPath="Test Suites/${katalonTestSuiteName}" \
                -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome (headless)" \
                -apiKey=${secret}
                """
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here details of jenkins log**

```
+ pwd
/katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon
+ ls
build.gradle
console.properties
debug.log
FRM-Katalon.prj
Include
Object Repository
Profiles
Scripts
settings
Test Cases
Test Suites
+ /katalon01/katalon-studio-engine/katalonc -noSplash -runMode=console -projectPath=/katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/FRM-Katalon.prj -retry=0 '-testSuiteCollectionPath=Test Suites/FRM_Katalon' -executionProfile=default '-browserType=Chrome (headless)' -apiKey= 8490e2f6-9949-4610-b043-*******
Katalon workspace folder is set to default location: /tmp/session-f1cdbf48
Starting Groovy-Eclipse compiler resolver.  Specified compiler level: unspecified
177 2.4.7.xx-2016111****-e46 = ACTIVE


INFO: Katalon Version: 7.5.2
INFO: Command-line arguments: -runMode=console -projectPath=/katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/FRM-Katalon.prj -retry=0 -testSuiteCollectionPath=Test Suites/FRM_Katalon -executionProfile=default -browserType=Chrome (headless) -apiKey=******** 8490e2f6-9949-4610-b043-********
INFO: User working dir: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon
INFO: Error log: /tmp/session-f1cdbf48/.metadata/.log
INFO: Katalon TestOps server URL: https://analytics.katalon.com
INFO: Katalon Store server URL: https://store.katalon.com
INFO: User home: /katalon01/jenkins-agent
INFO: Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
INFO: Java version: 1.8.0_262
INFO: Local OS: Linux 64bit
INFO: CPU load: 0%
INFO: Total memory: 7316 MB
INFO: Free memory: 1013 MB
Start getting machine ID on Linux
End getting machine ID on Linux c05973d029ca9e78c8*******
Start appending additional signatures
hardwareSerialNumber 
osDependentUsername jenkins
End appending additional signatures c05973d029ca9e78c8d1437*****__jenkins
INFO: Machine ID: 6546c254cb38a5280********


Activating...
Start activating offline...
Search for valid offline licenses in folder: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/.katalon/license
The number of valid offline licenses: 0
Offline activation failed.
Start activating online...
Cleaning up workspace
Opening project file: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/FRM-Katalon.prj
Warning! Please run Katalon execution command outside of the project folder.
Generating global variables...
Parsing custom keywords...
Project 'FRM-Katalon' opened
Start reloading plugins...
Katalon version: 7.5.2
Plugin info URL: https://store.katalon.com/api/products/ks?appVersion=7.5.2&appType=ENGINE&licenseType=ENTERPRISE
Start check license task
chromedriver is located at default location: /katalon01/katalon-studio-engine/configuration/resources/drivers/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver. In case your browser is updated to a newer version, please use this command to update chromdriver: --config -webui.autoUpdateDrivers=true

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/FRM_Katalon - 20200814_092512................................0/7(0%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/Test Suite_Application Controller - Chrome - 20200814_092512.0/7(0%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Launcher status after execution process completed: Running
Start writing execution.uuid file to folder: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/Test Suite_Application Controller/20200814_092512
Start generating JUnit report folder at: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/Test Suite_Application Controller/20200814_092512...
JUnit report were generated at folder: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/Test Suite_Application Controller/20200814_092512

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/FRM_Katalon - 20200814_092512...............................4/7(57%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/Test Suite_Application Controller - Chrome - 20200814_092512........
........................................................................4/7(57%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Uploading report to Katalon TestOps...
Start sending test result to Katalon TestOps
Uploading log files of test suite collection
Sending file: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/Test Suite_Application Controller/20200814_092512/execution.uuid
Sending file: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/Test Suite_Application Controller/20200814_092512/execution0.log
Sending file: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/Test Suite_Application Controller/20200814_092512/execution.properties
Sending file: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/Test Suite_Application Controller/20200814_092512/JUnit_Report.xml
Sending file: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/FRM_Katalon/20200814_092512/JUnit_Report.xml
Sending file: /katalon01/jenkins-agent/workspace/Framework/framework-katalon/Reports/20200814_092512/FRM_Katalon/20200814_092512/20200814_092512.rp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/FRM_Katalon - 20200814_092512..............................7/7(100%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/Test Suite_Application Controller - Chrome - 20200814_092512........
.......................................................................7/7(100%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Katalon TestOps: Start uploading report to Katalon TestOps server: https://analytics.katalon.com
Katalon TestOps - Execution URL: https://analytics.katalon.com/from-ks/execution-result?teamId=50***&projectId=62***&id=6941***
End sending to Katalon TestOps
Report has been sent to Katalon TestOps

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/FRM_Katalon - 20200814_092512..............................7/7(100%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/Test Suite_Application Controller - Chrome - 20200814_092512........
.......................................................................7/7(100%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Execution completed. Exit code: 1.
Start clean up session
End check license task
End clean up session
Start release license task
License released
End release license task
All launchers terminated
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Posting build status of FAILED to bitbucketERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Here details of Katalon error log**

```
2020-08-14 08:40:21 - [TEST_CASE][FAILED] - Test Cases/Application Controller/TS-001_Login Logout Positive Case: Test Cases/Application Controller/TS-001_Login Logout Positive Case FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: 'http://10.172.**.***:3000/'
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:72)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:60)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$openBrowser.call(Unknown Source)
    at TS-001_Login Logout Positive Case.run(TS-001_Login Logout Positive Case:19)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:169)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:142)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:91)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1597394411452.run(TempTestSuite1597394411452.groovy:37)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'devopstools-katalon', ip: '10.172.**.***', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_262'
Driver info: driver.version: CChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x55edd4eed*** <unknown>

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver.execute(CChromeDriver.java:19))
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.doCall(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.call(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Chrome options with

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        ...
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t).

**UPDATE:**

To switch from Katalon keywords to Selenium commands use the DriverFactory library. Add this to the top of your script:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\test\\chromedriver.exe")

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)
```

For more information see [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/using_selenium_webdriver_katalon_studio.html#introduction).

Comment: where should I update chrome option? sorry i don't get it

Comment: sorry I delay all that stuff, I will try when I have time. Thanks for answering